# WooCommerce quantity minus and plus icons are not showing

Tags: php, jquery, woocommerce, icons, font-awesome

I'm having some trouble displaying the `+` and `-` quantity icons on the WooCommerce product page.

[image: error]

After much research I discovered that for some strange reason WordPress is giving the class name to the object in question wrong (setting `'fas fa-plus-circle'` instead of `'fa fa-plus-circle'`) and that is why it is not showing the icon.

[image: error2]

I have tried a thousand ways to change the class to the correct one using JavaScript and PHP in theme file editor *(for info I'm using Astra theme)*.

[image: error4]

I also tried to fix it with the HTML widget from Elementor, but I am unable to make it work like that neither.

[image: error3]

I would be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will handle multiple plus / minus FontAwesome icons, if there are multiple quantity fields, like in product loops (archive pages…) or in cart page... This jQuery code is enqueued and work for "minus-circle" and "plus-circle" FontAwesome icons.

The code replace everywhere the selector class `fas` with `fa` for "minus-circle" and "plus-circle" FontAwesome icons:

```php
add_action('template_redirect', 'fontawesome_5_free_quantity_buttons_js', 10);
function fontawesome_5_free_quantity_buttons_js() {
    wc_enqueue_js("$('i.fa-minus-circle,i.fa-plus-circle').each( function(index) {
    if( $(this).hasClass('fas') && ! $(this).hasClass('fa') ) {
        $(this).removeClass('fas').addClass('fa');
    }
    });");
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

Explanation: The plugin or the custom code that is generating thoses plus / minus FontAwesome icons, uses [FontAwesome 6 free](https://fontawesome.com/search?q=plus&o=r&m=free) *(`fas`)*… WooCommerce enables and use by default [FontAwesome 5 Free](https://fontawesome.com/v5/search?q=plus&o=r&m=free) *(`fa`)*.